# What are the methods to trace an array to the following criteria?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

The array:

```
var numberArray:Array= new Array(34,53,2,3,34,26,26,85,3,4,98,2,12);
```

1. How do I trace it so the output-panel will show every other item:  `"34,2,34,26,3,98,12"`
2. How do I trace the numbers that have a lower value than 10
3. How do I trace the even numbers in the array?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you clarify your #1 point (what significance that set of numbers has in relation to the original array)?

Comment: So. I tried doing (numberArray [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]); which gave me an error:
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 12 not found on Number and there is no default value.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Then I tried trace (numberArray[0],[2],[4],[6],[8],[10],[12],[14]); it traced the first element (34)  in the array correctly, but then it just listed the numbers i wrote in the array instead of every other element in the array that I wanted

Comment: #1 was a bit poorly written, my bad. I meant to say "How can I trace every other element in the array?"

Answer (score 3):

For the reference and general education: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#map()

```
// You can init Arrays with [] operator.
var numberArray:Array = [34,53,2,3,34,26,26,85,3,4,98,2,12];

trace(filter(numberArray, evenIndices));
trace(filter(numberArray, belowTen));
trace(filter(numberArray, evenValues));

// In AS3 you can pass method references as function arguments.
// That allows to compose a filtering method, just like Vector.map(...)

// This method will filter the original array 
// by the given criteria and return the filtered result.
// Criteria method must accept 2 arguments: element index and value.
function filter(source:Array, criteria:Function):Array
{
    var result:Array = new Array;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < source.length; i++)
        if (criteria(i, source[i]))
            result.push(source[i]);

    return result;
}

// Returns true if index is an even number.
function evenIndices(index:int, value:int):Boolean
{
    return index % 2 == 0;
}

// Returns true if value is less than 10.
function belowTen(index:int, value:int):Boolean
{
    return value < 10;
}

// Returns true if value is an even number.
function evenValues(index:int, value:int):Boolean
{
    return value % 2 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**var numberArray:Array = [34, 53, 2, 3, 34, 26, 26, 85];**

1.How do I trace it so the output-panel will show every-other item: "34,2,34,26,3,98,12"

```
getEventIndexiesOfArray(numberArray);
```

2.How do I trace the numbers that have a lower value than 10

```
lenghtLessthanTen(numberArray);
```

3.How do I trace the even numbers in the array?

```
checkArrayHasEventLenght(numberArray);
```

**1. getEventIndexiesOfArray() method for get event indexies elements from array.**

```
private function getEventIndexiesOfArray(source:Array):void
        {
            var resultArr:Array = [];
            for (var i:int = 0; i < source.length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    resultArr.push(source[i]);
            }
            trace("Even Indexies Array : " + resultArr.toString());
        }
```

**2.  lenghtLessthanTen() method for check that array lenght is lessthan 10 or not.**

```
 private function lenghtLessthanTen(source:Array):void
            {
                if (source.length < 10)
                    trace("Array containt lessthan Ten elements");
            }
```

**3. checkArrayHasEventLenght() method check that array containt even lenght or not.**

```
private function checkArrayHasEventLenght(source:Array):void
        {
            if (source.length % 2 == 0)
                trace("Array has even number of elenter code hereements");
        }
```